# Custom row with circular ImageView and textview in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to create a custom row for my `RecyclerView`. Here is my custom row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/customLevelLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/levelImage"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/gameText"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/circular_background" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                tools:text="Tracing" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/gameProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:padding="45dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lockImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/lock_background"
        android:padding="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lock"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

The problem is, I have to define a predefined height of the custom row i.e `170dp` currently. I am facing 2 problems because of this:

1) If I open the application in a small screen or a tablet device. The custom row is looking ugly i.e I loose the circular shape of the `ImageView`.

2) The text doesn't remain at the centre if there is a slight change in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#00000000">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/customLevelLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/levelImage"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
               android:src="@drawable/circular_background" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="45sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            tools:text="Tracing"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/gameProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:padding="45dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lockImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/lock_background"
    android:padding="45dp"
    android:src="@drawable/lock"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Good luck to you.@Hiren

Comment: The `ImageView` at the bottom of the layout which in invisible is taking complete height. What to do ? @KeLiuyue

Comment: If you set ` android:visibility="gone"` in your layout,it will be not taking height in your layout. If your set `android:visibility="visible"` or `android:visibility="invisible"`,it will be taking the height .

Comment: Actually programmatically I am making it `visible` at certain point of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try This. You can use `Linearlayout` as root than for image and text use `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/customLevelLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/levelImage"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/circular_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                tools:text="Tracing" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/gameProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:padding="45dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lockImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/lock_background"
        android:padding="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lock"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **constrain layout** which helps you to set image like you want just by drag and drop and add constrain

Comment: can you provide an implementation of the above layout using `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: add this dependency compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

For supporting multiple screen. First you have to go through this link
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Once you fix first issue, second issue also will get fix

Comment: I have already created different dimen.xml for multiple screens.